# HTACCESS Rewrite Multidimensional (eg: www.mysite.com/variable2/variable2

Tags: .htaccess

Hey, I'm aware I could use a HTACCESS rewrite to write

> www.mysite.com/index.php?page=hello&subpage=welcome

to

> www.mysite.com/1/hello/welcome

But is there any way to rewrite it to

> www.mysite.com/hello/welcome

??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uh, just modify your rule.  Something like this ought to work:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/(.*?)/$  index.php?page=$1&subpage=$2 [NC,L]
```